# Keeping old item versions

Tags: content-management, versions

We have some items with 100+ versions. We have decided to recycle the old item versions and keep the last 10 versions. By default, anything in the recycle bin will be permanently deleted in 30 days.

The issue is we will lose the old version items in 30 days in the recycle bin. We don't want to delete the versions permanently. Due to some legal requirements, we will need to refer back to any item version whenever we want.

Is there any third-party integration that has anyone used which can keep every item version so we can refer to any past version at any time? Or anyone has come up with a solution for keeping the items up to 10 versions and storing the old versions somewhere and not deleting them permanently?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of recycle bin you can choose to archive the item, as it won't delete the data but manage in a different way, sitecore have OOTB capability for it and you can get different modules and other options in marketplace for same(e.g. Version Pruner).
Some links for your reference:

- [https://sitecoreconfig.wordpress.com/2015/09/21/archiving-sitecore-content-and-the-recycle-bin/#:~:text=The%20Sitecore%20archive%20is%20similar,this%20archiving%20framework%20is%20extensible](https://sitecoreconfig.wordpress.com/2015/09/21/archiving-sitecore-content-and-the-recycle-bin/#:%7E:text=The%20Sitecore%20archive%20is%20similar,this%20archiving%20framework%20is%20extensible).
- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/archive-and-restore-an-item.html

We also do it in our project using PS script (which internaly uses ArchiveVersion cmdlet).
Let me know if it helps or do you need any other information.

Comment: @owais Please accept the answer, if it solves your issue.